# Angular JS 2 depth dynamic model

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, multidimensional-array, model

I want to create a dynamic model in angularjs. There is not seem to be a way to work as i want. I tried to declare as array but not even then worked

**Controller**

```
$scope.cccdirect = {}
$scope.items = [
   { 
       id: 1231
       title: "Product 1"
       qty: 2
       price: "25"
       subtotal: "50"
       direct = true
   }
 .....
]
```

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <select data-ng-model="cccdirect[item.id][direct]">
                <option value="1000">Απομακρυσμένο κατάστημα</option>
                <option value="1001">Άμεση Ενδοδιακίνηση</option>
                <option value="1002">Εβδομμαδιαία Ενδοδιακίνηση</option>
            </select>

            <select ng-model="cccdirect[item.id][sendtype]" ng-options="t.title for t in types" data-ng-change="checkForCompaniesRow(item.id)"></select>
            <select data-ng-show="cccdirect[item.id][show_companies]" ng-model="cccdirect[item.id][sendcompany]" ng-options="t.title for t in companies"></select>
            <select data-ng-show="cccdirect[item.id][show_ktel]" ng-model="cccdirect[item.id][sendktel]" ng-options="t.title for t in ktel"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

What i want is to get a model looked like this:

```
cccdirect = {[
  item.id --> 1251:{
   direct:1000,
   sendtype:1002,
   sendcompanies:23,
   sendktel:0
 },
  item.id --> 2572:{
   direct:1000,
   sendtype:1002,
   sendcompanies:23,
   sendktel:0
 },

]}
```

Comment: Array should be fine. What error you are getting or what is the outcome of this?

Comment: At first it seems to work but when you select the dropdown it gives TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: Manually initializing the object should do the trick: add `ng-init="cccdirect[item.id] = cccdirect[item.id] || {}"`, right after `ng-repeat`